# Solr How I query number field when i use complexphrase

Tags: solr

I am trying to query a specific number within a string. For instance, my query looks like this:

```
{!complexphrase} info:"Robert Bosch *1956*"~10000 AND type:3
```

then if it return 0 result
but if I remove **{!complexphrase}** it returns a result but it is not my expected result because it is not a complex phrase query.

How I can use complex phrases with number field?

Comment: There is nothing special about numbers, but it would depend on how you're processing the field (i.e. the analysis chain for that field. What's the reason for using a complexphrasequery here in the first case?

Comment: i use complexphrasequery  for case "{!complexphrase} info:"Robert Bosch 1956 ID *1650"~10000" when data is "Robert Bosch ...1956 ....CN1650"